# Draggable uiview with uitextview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I m iOS beginner and i have created following hierarchy,

```
 1.  uiview

   2.   uiview

      3.    uitextview
```

The size of uitextview and uiview(2) is same.

The question is, **i want to make the uiview draggable by dragging on uitextview...???**

I have tried this following but it cant works for me..

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
       UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
       CGPoint location = [aTouch locationInView:self.noteTextView];
       [UIView beginAnimations:@"Dragging A DraggableView" context:nil];
       self.frame = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
       [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

here noteTextView is an object of UITextView..

Comment: Y don't you use a scrollview for this??

Comment: No, i cant used scrollview, bcoz i want that uiview like as small note.So it will not contain much data..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drag a view you can use the following code ([from ray's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)):

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, 
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

remember to enable user interaction on the view.

Also, not sure what you are doing but it sounds like you want to use a label not a UITextView.

Comment: No..i want to create a note which contain text as well as image, now i m trying this only for text so i have added the uitextview over the uiview(2), later on i will add uiimageview to put image...and uiview(1) is like as a container for all these small uiviews(2)...

Comment: Right. So if you want both to move you need to move the view not the text and you can use the code I gave you.

Comment: Instead of self.view i used self.noteTextView and its shifting the uitextview and i want to shift entire uiview(2) when u drag the uitextview...

Comment: If you want the text to move the view add the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the UITextView but in the function above change `self.view` to the name of the view you want to move.